# Using JQuery's post function in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to post to localhost server from within a chrome extension and it doesn't seem to work.

Here are my files:

manifest:

```
{
"name": "Send to server",

"version": "1.1",

"background": { "page": "background.html"},

"permissions": ["experimental", "tabs", "<all_urls>"],

"browser_action": {"name": "Send to server", "default_icon": "icon.png", "default_popup":"popup.html" },

"icons": { "16": "16.png" },

"manifest_version": 2

}
```

The background.html is very brief, it just points to "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"
and to
"background.js".
(I use it just to be able to include JQuery and use it at background.js. Is there another way for it?)

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(SendToServer);

function SendToServer(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 

    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete'){
        chrome.experimental.infobars.show({
                tabId: tab.id,
                path: "infobar.html"
            });

            var strVar = "A page was loaded";

            alert("Before sending: " + strVar);

            $.post("http://localhost/MyDomain", {var: strVar}, 
                function(strVar ) { alert("Sending..."); }
            );
        }
  })
};
```

Now, alert("Before sending: " + strVar); is performed, so till here I'm doing well. But the .post isn't done.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug your background page you will find out that there is a security error. You are trying to load javascript from remote source (ajax.googleapis.com) while you haven't explicitly allowed that in the manifest file. And without jQuery, `$.post` can't run. You need to relax default [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-remote-script) (be sure to load jQuery over https).

If fact, what you should **actually** do in this particular case, is to include jQuery file in your extension and load it accordingly in `backtround.html`. Extension is not a website, remote call takes a lot of time compared to simple HDD fetch. In addition, using remote javascript files makes extension unusable/unstable when there is no internet connection.

Comment: I followed your second advice, which is obviously the recommended one, and it works. Thank you!